# cakephp data getting posted

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have a form and I want to see it in fiddler that what data is getting posted when form is submitted. I am not able to see anything. How do u debug in cakephp. I am a newbie in it

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must have `Configure::write('debug',2);` defined.

then you can use `debug($data)`; to debug any data.

also in views or layouts you can have

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

to output any database queries that had took place.

Comment: Look at this for more information: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1191/Using-the-Debugger-Class

Answer (score 2):

Inside app/config/core.php make sure the 'debug' value is 1 or 2 . t

If you use 1 warning and errors(if exists) will display 
If you use 2 warning and errors(if exists) will display and all the sql query will display(that queries are runs on that page)

Answer (score 1):

Within app/config/core.php make sure the 'debug' value is greater than 0.

For any value you would like to see, call the Cake 'pr' function to output it to the page. pr() will automatically expand any nested arrays and data structures.

Answer (score 1):

you have to print data by using

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->data);
echo "</pre>";
```

in this,Not required to 'debug' value is 1 or 2 .